# Module Slick Carousel Drupal 7 - View option X carousel - fullwidth : change style width of slide

Tags: drupal-7, view, slick.js

All is in the title.

I can't find how to configure the width of the slides.

```
<div class="slick__slide slide slide--5 slide--grid slick-slide slick-cloned slick-active" data-slick-index="-1" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="-1" style="width: 263px;">
```

The config on admin/configuration/media/slick doesn't affect the size of the slides.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the configuration of number of slide to show (Administration/Configuration/Media/Slick carousel>>list>>settings>>Slides to show)

But in Administration/Configuration/Media/Slick carousel
I couldn't access first to the entire configuration (trouble with slick admin CSS) unless in the tab UI I disabled the option "Enable Slick admin CSS".
And also I used the settings X carousel of the slick example.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a different setting on the view that clash with the settings from the module, or maybe the container div has a CSS rule so it might not go full width ? (I'm just guessing here)

I had few issues with the slick drupal module, 
what I did was to use js instead